# Drupal ImageCache Action Features?

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-modules

I am trying to create a scrolling image list on a Drupal site. Similar to the one at the bottom of [this page](http://iudm.org/). Is this a feature of Drupal's ImageCache Action? If not, how would I do this is Drupal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Purpose of imagecache is to provide image of different sizes as needed. This is generally useful for thumbnail display like here: http://www.ifood.tv/recipes

For your requirement use this module: http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel